# What should I configure SVN to ignore in my Delphi projects?

Tags: delphi, svn, tortoisesvn

What files should I tell Tortoise SVN to ignore when committing to a repository?

In particular I am interested in practical information such as whether to include such files as `*.dproj.2007` etc that seem to appear but may not be needed.

Comment: Sorry, but it was meant to elicit practical information such as whether to include such files as *.dproj.2007 etc that seem to appear but may not be needed.

Comment: As you speak about XE & XE2... I'm using the embedded SVN client... from the Project Manager, right click, SVN submenu... Otherwise, I will begin to add all the files with an extension which contains **~**

Comment: I suggest you ask about specific files and extensions.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I use these in D2007, which seem to still work fine in XE and XE2:

```
*.dcu *.~* *.ddp *.exe *.map *.bak *.obj *.dsk 
*.err *.log *.tmp *.identcache *.tvsconfig  __history *.todo 
ModelSupport* *.local
```

I don't include `ModelSupport` because I don't use the IDE's modeling stuff, so there's no point in versioning it if it's created by mistake. I also don't version anything in the `__history` folder, as that's just temporary versioning between checkins; once the checkin to SVN is made, it's not necessary any longer.

(I disagree with Chris about `*.res`, BTW, especially when it comes to XE2. Resource files can be created now using `Project|Resources and Images`, and those go directly into a resource file. Since the resource\image may be actually coming from somewhere else not in the current folder, and the image file might accidentally not be checked in, I keep the `.res` file now. I also keep the project file; it has all the paths and compiler options set. If something happens where that needs to change, it's easy to just remove the project file and let the IDE recreate it as needed.)

Comment: To clarify - we DO checkin .res files, but only when we've made a meaningful change.  Specifically, our automated build system increments version numbers in the .res and we don't want those to be clobbered by unnecessary checkins.  So this is probably specific to our environment.

Comment: Makes sense. We do version # changes manually only, and tag versions at the point the number changes, so the automatic increments don't affect us. :)

Answer (score 7):

Using Delphi2005, our team has long ago adopted this:

*.bdsproj *.scc *.suo *.user *.~* *.local *.identcache *.dsk obj bin testing __history *.o *.lo *.la *.al .libs *.so *.so.[0-9]* *.a *.pyc *.pyo *.rej *~ #*# .#* .*.swp .DS_Store

Not sure if they're all needed or not, or what some of them are.  I didn't come up with it, just following our internal wiki....

Along those lines, you should look at server-side pre-commit hooks.  We've got a pre-commit trigger that dis-allows check of .bdsproj, .dpr, and .res files unless a specific tag is included in the comment:  [Add Project File] [Add Res File].  If you try to commit a .bdsproj, .res, or .dpr without those tags, the commit will fail the audit and be rejected, and an embarrassing e-mail will be sent to the whole dev team.  This is because these files rarely have any legitimate changes. If you need to add a unit to a project, fine, do it and include the tag with the checkin, and it'll be fine. The tag says "I know what I'm doing, and I have a good reason to change this file".  Otherwise, you've got all sorts of crap being checked in - rev numbers, path changes, packages coming and going, etc..

We've also got some grep filters in the pre-commit, looking for certain things being added. Like unwanted "skins" units from DevExpress, because some developer has all of the skins installed and the IDE decided to add them.  Or MadExcept, because someone left it turned on after debugging something (we don't allow MadExcept in production on this particular project, for a variety of reasons).  Stuff like that.

Update: because our environment is non-typical, I removed *.res from the list above.

Comment: In Delphi XE2, you can finally remove .RES files from the repo without odd side effects.  If you had decided to commit only .rc files in Delphi versions prior to that, you got some weird IDE behaviours I'll bet!

Answer (score 1):

The official Emba answer is here:

https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/File_Extensions_of_Files_Generated_by_RAD_Studio

At time of this writing, I believe this list of types to be incomplete (example: there is no mention of Android .obb files), but the wiki format allows suggestions, and the page does appear to be updated.

You could also look at this:

https://delphi.fandom.com/wiki/Delphi_File_Extensions

although it seems to be less than complete, and not updated very often (Example: no mention of android-related files at all.)

Comment: Since you seem to know about the files used when developing for Android, you could update the list in the Delphi Wiki. (I would have done that myself, but I don't now much about Android development.)

Comment: I've only just started learning about this. I know enough to make the comment I did, and be sure it's factual, but not much more. I was surprised that this thread didn't already contain a reference to the Embarcadero docwiki. Once I have worked out how to post a comment on the docwiki asking them to update it, I will do so.

Comment: I wasn't talking about the Embarcadero Docwiki but about the Delphi Wiki (your second link). There you only need to create an account (If I remember correctly, you only need to provide an email for that) and can immediately start editing the pages.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Understood.